# Ruby on Rails ActionController: scope combined with inclusive or

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, conditional-statements

I'd like to combine two scope condition with an inclusive `or`.

I tried with: `scope :myscope, lambda { |u| where(cond1: u.id) or where(cond2: u.id)}`, but it doesn't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides some methods that bypasses the need to write SQL, but in this case you'll need to go put a very little effort and write a small piece of SQL.

```
scope :myscope, -> { |u| where("cond1 = ? OR cond2 = ?", u.id, u.id) }
```

You can also be more concise and use

```
scope :myscope, -> { |u| where("cond1 = :id OR cond2 = :id", id: u.id) }
```

There is nothing wrong in writing some SQL. Don't fall into the trap "if I can't write it in Ruby, it's ugly or not the Rails way".

Answer (score 0):

There is a query method `#or` which you can use like this:

```
where(cond1: u.id).or(cond2: u.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 will implement "OR" as @jphager2's answer stated, but meanwhile you have to get your hands a little dirty :

```
scope :myscope, lambda {where ["cond1 = ? OR cond2 = ?", u.id, u.id]}
```

Comment: It's not dirty, it's called SQL and there's nothing wrong with it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this:-

```
scope :myscope, lambda { |u| where('cond1 = ? OR cond2 = ?', u.id, u.id)}
```